# How to get specific values from Google API Json response?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, google-api, google-cloud-functions

I am using google cloud functions / node.js to get a response from Google's autocomplete API. The response I get is below, I want to get all the "description" values, but everything I've tried fails.

```
console.log('got response');
var parsedResults = JSON.parse(body);
console.log(parsedResults);
```

My latest attempt:

```
var predictions = parsedResults.predictions;
var description = predictions.description;
console.log(description);
```

```
{
  "predictions" : [
    {
      "description" : "New York, NY, USA",
      "matched_substrings" : [
        {
          "length" : 3,
          "offset" : 0
        }
      ],
      "place_id" : "ChIJOwg_06VPwokRYv534QaPC8g",
      "reference" : "ChIJOwg_06VPwokRYv534QaPC8g",
      "structured_formatting" : {
        "main_text" : "New York",
        "main_text_matched_substrings" : [
          {
            "length" : 3,
            "offset" : 0
          }
        ],
        "secondary_text" : "NY, USA"
      },
      "terms" : [
        {
          "offset" : 0,
          "value" : "New York"
        },
        {
          "offset" : 10,
          "value" : "NY"
        },
        {
          "offset" : 14,
          "value" : "USA"
        }
      ],
      "types" : [ "locality", "political", "geocode" ]
    },
    {
      "description" : "New Orleans, LA, USA",
      "matched_substrings" : [
        {
          "length" : 3,
          "offset" : 0
        }
      ],
      "place_id" : "ChIJZYIRslSkIIYRtNMiXuhbBts",
      "reference" : "ChIJZYIRslSkIIYRtNMiXuhbBts",
      "structured_formatting" : {
        "main_text" : "New Orleans",
        "main_text_matched_substrings" : [
          {
            "length" : 3,
            "offset" : 0
          }
        ],
        "secondary_text" : "LA, USA"
      },
      "terms" : [
        {
          "offset" : 0,
          "value" : "New Orleans"
        },
        {
          "offset" : 13,
          "value" : "LA"
        },
        {
          "offset" : 17,
          "value" : "USA"
        }
      ],
      "types" : [ "locality", "political", "geocode" ]
    },
    {
      "description" : "New Delhi, Delhi, India",
      "matched_substrings" : [
        {
          "length" : 3,
          "offset" : 0
        }
      ],
      "place_id" : "ChIJLbZ-NFv9DDkRzk0gTkm3wlI",
      "reference" : "ChIJLbZ-NFv9DDkRzk0gTkm3wlI",
      "structured_formatting" : {
        "main_text" : "New Delhi",
        "main_text_matched_substrings" : [
          {
            "length" : 3,
            "offset" : 0
          }
        ],
        "secondary_text" : "Delhi, India"
      },
      "terms" : [
        {
          "offset" : 0,
          "value" : "New Delhi"
        },
        {
          "offset" : 11,
          "value" : "Delhi"
        },
        {
          "offset" : 18,
          "value" : "India"
        }
      ],
      "types" : [ "locality", "political", "geocode" ]
    },
    {
      "description" : "Newquay, UK",
      "matched_substrings" : [
        {
          "length" : 3,
          "offset" : 0
        }
      ],
      "place_id" : "ChIJh1a5WhEMa0gRY1JU4PEam8Q",
      "reference" : "ChIJh1a5WhEMa0gRY1JU4PEam8Q",
      "structured_formatting" : {
        "main_text" : "Newquay",
        "main_text_matched_substrings" : [
          {
            "length" : 3,
            "offset" : 0
          }
        ],
        "secondary_text" : "UK"
      },
      "terms" : [
        {
          "offset" : 0,
          "value" : "Newquay"
        },
        {
          "offset" : 9,
          "value" : "UK"
        }
      ],
      "types" : [ "locality", "political", "geocode" ]
    },
    {
      "description" : "Newport Beach, CA, USA",
      "matched_substrings" : [
        {
          "length" : 3,
          "offset" : 0
        }
      ],
      "place_id" : "ChIJ3bO_xLbo3IARvVmLZFSVVPE",
      "reference" : "ChIJ3bO_xLbo3IARvVmLZFSVVPE",
      "structured_formatting" : {
        "main_text" : "Newport Beach",
        "main_text_matched_substrings" : [
          {
            "length" : 3,
            "offset" : 0
          }
        ],
        "secondary_text" : "CA, USA"
      },
      "terms" : [
        {
          "offset" : 0,
          "value" : "Newport Beach"
        },
        {
          "offset" : 15,
          "value" : "CA"
        },
        {
          "offset" : 19,
          "value" : "USA"
        }
      ],
      "types" : [ "locality", "political", "geocode" ]
    }
  ],
  "status" : "OK"
}
```

Comment: `but everything I've tried fails` - you haven't tried anything in your question ... show what you've tried, that way you learn more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Predictions is an array

With more than one description

so `predictions.description` would never work

this does

```js
const parsedResults = {
    "predictions": [{
            "description": "New York, NY, USA",
            "matched_substrings": [{
                    "length": 3,
                    "offset": 0
                }
            ],
            "place_id": "ChIJOwg_06VPwokRYv534QaPC8g",
            "reference": "ChIJOwg_06VPwokRYv534QaPC8g",
            "structured_formatting": {
                "main_text": "New York",
                "main_text_matched_substrings": [{
                        "length": 3,
                        "offset": 0
                    }
                ],
                "secondary_text": "NY, USA"
            },
            "terms": [{
                    "offset": 0,
                    "value": "New York"
                }, {
                    "offset": 10,
                    "value": "NY"
                }, {
                    "offset": 14,
                    "value": "USA"
                }
            ],
            "types": ["locality", "political", "geocode"]
        }, {
            "description": "New Orleans, LA, USA",
            "matched_substrings": [{
                    "length": 3,
                    "offset": 0
                }
            ],
            "place_id": "ChIJZYIRslSkIIYRtNMiXuhbBts",
            "reference": "ChIJZYIRslSkIIYRtNMiXuhbBts",
            "structured_formatting": {
                "main_text": "New Orleans",
                "main_text_matched_substrings": [{
                        "length": 3,
                        "offset": 0
                    }
                ],
                "secondary_text": "LA, USA"
            },
            "terms": [{
                    "offset": 0,
                    "value": "New Orleans"
                }, {
                    "offset": 13,
                    "value": "LA"
                }, {
                    "offset": 17,
                    "value": "USA"
                }
            ],
            "types": ["locality", "political", "geocode"]
        }, {
            "description": "New Delhi, Delhi, India",
            "matched_substrings": [{
                    "length": 3,
                    "offset": 0
                }
            ],
            "place_id": "ChIJLbZ-NFv9DDkRzk0gTkm3wlI",
            "reference": "ChIJLbZ-NFv9DDkRzk0gTkm3wlI",
            "structured_formatting": {
                "main_text": "New Delhi",
                "main_text_matched_substrings": [{
                        "length": 3,
                        "offset": 0
                    }
                ],
                "secondary_text": "Delhi, India"
            },
            "terms": [{
                    "offset": 0,
                    "value": "New Delhi"
                }, {
                    "offset": 11,
                    "value": "Delhi"
                }, {
                    "offset": 18,
                    "value": "India"
                }
            ],
            "types": ["locality", "political", "geocode"]
        }, {
            "description": "Newquay, UK",
            "matched_substrings": [{
                    "length": 3,
                    "offset": 0
                }
            ],
            "place_id": "ChIJh1a5WhEMa0gRY1JU4PEam8Q",
            "reference": "ChIJh1a5WhEMa0gRY1JU4PEam8Q",
            "structured_formatting": {
                "main_text": "Newquay",
                "main_text_matched_substrings": [{
                        "length": 3,
                        "offset": 0
                    }
                ],
                "secondary_text": "UK"
            },
            "terms": [{
                    "offset": 0,
                    "value": "Newquay"
                }, {
                    "offset": 9,
                    "value": "UK"
                }
            ],
            "types": ["locality", "political", "geocode"]
        }, {
            "description": "Newport Beach, CA, USA",
            "matched_substrings": [{
                    "length": 3,
                    "offset": 0
                }
            ],
            "place_id": "ChIJ3bO_xLbo3IARvVmLZFSVVPE",
            "reference": "ChIJ3bO_xLbo3IARvVmLZFSVVPE",
            "structured_formatting": {
                "main_text": "Newport Beach",
                "main_text_matched_substrings": [{
                        "length": 3,
                        "offset": 0
                    }
                ],
                "secondary_text": "CA, USA"
            },
            "terms": [{
                    "offset": 0,
                    "value": "Newport Beach"
                }, {
                    "offset": 15,
                    "value": "CA"
                }, {
                    "offset": 19,
                    "value": "USA"
                }
            ],
            "types": ["locality", "political", "geocode"]
        }
    ],
    "status": "OK"
};

const descriptions = parsedResults.predictions.map(({description:d})=>d);
console.log(descriptions);
```

Comment: Thanks aton, works perfect! All the examples/tutorials I've gone through show the most basic examples. I'm trying to understand what `(({description:d})=>d)` does? I understand it maps all `description` values from the array... then it is making a new array from `d` values?

Comment: actually, that bit could've been just `const descriptions = parsedResults.predictions.map(({description})=>description);` - I tend to try to write short code - the most common version would be `const descriptions = parsedResults.predictions.map(item=>item.description);` - all three do the same thing though

Comment: I see. Thanks for the explanation!